# Download multiple PDFs using cURL and PHP

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I'm kind of new to cURL and I'm wondering how I could download multiple PDFs from http://somedomain.com/MyPDFFiles/ to a folder on my server: http://mydomain.com/PDFs/

I have all the file names but I have no idea if it is possible to use cURL and PHP to obtain this.

Can someone explain how this would work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multicurl to simultaneously send curl requests

https://github.com/jmathai/php-multi-curl

Comment: Thanx for the link! Solved my issues :)